# Rendering things based on conditions within conditions

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

So I am trying to implement `@pnp/sp`'s `PlaceHolder` component:

```
public render(): React.ReactElement<Props> { 
    let buttons;

    if (this.props.context.pageContext.web.permissions.hasPermission(SPPermission.addListItems)) {
        buttons = <div>
            <PrimaryButton 
                onClick={this._fetchJobs.bind(this)} text="Refresh Jobs" 
            />
            <PrimaryButton 
                onClick={this._showCreateJobPanel.bind(this)} 
                text="Create New Job" 
            />
        </div>;
    }

    return (
        <div className= { styles.container }>
            { this.state.locations ? (
                <Placeholder
                iconName='Edit'
                iconText="Configure the Delivery Board"
                description="Please configure your Delivery Board"
                buttonLabel="Configure"
                // onConfigure={this.props.fPropertyPaneOpen} />
                />                      
            ) : (
                <WebPartTitle
                displayMode={this.props.displayMode}
                title={this.props.title}
                updateProperty={this.props.updateProperty}
                />      

                {buttons} <-- line 216
            )}
        </div>
    )

}
```

Trying to add in the `{buttons}` is causing an error:

```
[10:28:58] Error - [tsc] src/Components/file.tsx(216,7): error TS1005: ')' expected.
```

I'm pretty sure it has todo with the nested brackets {} but I don't know enough to understand why or how to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only put one expression in each of the cases of the ternary operator. Assuming you're on react 16 or later, you can solve this by wrapping it in a fragment:

```
{ this.state.locations ? (
  <Placeholder
  iconName='Edit'
  iconText="Configure the Delivery Board"
  description="Please configure your Delivery Board"
  buttonLabel="Configure"
  />                      
) : (
  <React.Fragment>
    <WebPartTitle
    displayMode={this.props.displayMode}
    title={this.props.title}
    updateProperty={this.props.updateProperty}
    />      
    {buttons}
  </React.Fragment>
)}
```

Prior to react 16 you could use a div, or you could use an array. Here it is with an array:

```
{ this.state.locations ? (
  <Placeholder
  iconName='Edit'
  iconText="Configure the Delivery Board"
  description="Please configure your Delivery Board"
  buttonLabel="Configure"
  />                      
) : (
  [
    <WebPartTitle
      displayMode={this.props.displayMode}
      title={this.props.title}
      updateProperty={this.props.updateProperty}
    />,
    buttons
  ]
)}
```